# what's wrong with match() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

what's wrong with match() in javascript ?

```
var path = "D:\Programs\DeveloperTools";
var patt=/.+\\/g;
alert(path.match(patt));
```

The Result Should Be :
D:\Programs\

Comment: When I first read this, I couldn't help but think you were very sad about your Programs directory.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. The real question is, what's wrong with your Javascript usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape:

```
var path = "D:\\Programs\\DeveloperTools";
```

Now `match` and `alert` the `path` and you will get the expected result. And here's the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eqYFs/).